# Deploy a dacpac on encrypted database disable encryption on this database

Tags: database, encryption, dacpac

I'm on a project that manage a SqlServer database.

We have a SqlServer Database solution in visual studio that define  the database structure, and we use the generated dacpac  to update existing database regularly.

Now I enabled encryption on my database as explained here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx
My database seems to be encrypted like said sys.databases.is_encrypted field.

But each time I deploy a new dacPac on my existing database to update it, the encryption is automatically disabled and I don't know why.

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131532/enable-tde-when-publishing-dacpac/131535

This is property to enable in visual studio project